# Code trajectory in large Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I've recently started a new job which has me plunged into a massive Visual Studio project which I'm having to reverse engineer. Unfortunately there is not much documentation to go on. There are numerous folders each containing dozens of classes and there is a complex interaction with web scripts. Is there any way I can follow the code trajectory as the program is running without guessing with breakpoints or starting at the first line and stepping over thousands of lines? I'm also having difficulty determining what is actually launching the application. A startup object is not set and the first line running appears to be a standard library JS script. Some advice, either on the specifics or the general concepts, would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have visual studio architect / enterprise version you can create maps of all classes and packages and also draw sequence diagrams